# 12Factor App: Capturing stdout/stderr logs with Fluentd

Tags: logging, fluentd, 12factor

By reading the following post from [12factor](http://12factor.net/logs) I have come up with a question I'd like to check how you guys handle this.

Basically, an app should write directly to stdout/stderr. Is there anyway to redirect these streams **directly to fluentd** (not bound to rsyslog/syslog)? As I become more aware of fluentd, I believe it would be a great tool for log aggregation from multiple apps/platforms.

The main reasoning for this is, if the app is cross-platform, rsyslog/syslog may not be available, and as I understand, using logging frameworks (which need the required configuration for them to work) would be a violation of the 12factor.

Thanks!

Comment: with docker everything becomes easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure your process manager to use fluentd.

> ["Twelve-factor app processes should [...] rely on the operating system’s process manager (such as Upstart, a distributed process manager on a cloud platform, or a tool like Foreman in development) to manage output streams [...]."](http://12factor.net/concurrency)

Basically, the idea is that log redirection is a concern of the process manager. [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), for example, usually relies on [logger](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/logger.1.html), which has an option (`-u`) to write to a [Unix Domain Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). In turn, you can [configure fluentd to use that same socket as an input stream](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_unix).

[Fluentd supports a lot of input streams](http://www.fluentd.org/datasources) (they call them data sources), which should provide a solution for just about any environment & process manager you might be using (which we need to know in order to provide a more complete solution).

Answer (score 3):

This is still an experimental program, but you can take a look at stdout-hook.

- https://github.com/treasure-data/stdout-hook

This program reads STDOUT output from child process, and post the records to Fluentd.